# I want to filter out data from a dataset based on the user's input in the search box. However the filtering process doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, filter, frontend

Here's an overview of what I have tried so far:

1. I have a searchInput element where users can type their search query.
2. I'm using a function to handle the filtering process when the searchInput value changes.
3. The filtering function loops through the dataset and compares each item against the searchInput value to determine whether it should be shown or hidden.
   However, when I type in the searchInput, the data remains unchanged, and the filtering doesn't seem to take effect.

Filter Data Function

```
function filterData(searchText, restaurants) {
  const filterData = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
    restaurant.info.name.includes(searchText)
  );
  return filterData;
}
```

```
  import { restruntList } from "../constants"; // JSON data

  const Body = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restruntList);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setSearchText(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="search-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            //Filter data
            const data = filterData(searchText, restaurants);

            //update state - restaurant variable
            setRestaurants(data);
          }}
        >
          Search{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
      //UI
      <div className="restrunt-list">
        {restruntList.map((restaurant) => {
          return <RestruntCard {...restaurant.info} key={restaurant.info.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

restruntList JSON Data Format

```
export const restruntList = [
  {
    info: {
      id: "23719",
      name: "McDonald's",
      cloudinaryImageId: "ee5f8e06b300efc07c9fe3f4df40dfc4",
      locality: "JM Road",
      areaName: "Shivajinagar",
      costForTwo: "₹400 for two",
      cuisines: ["Burgers", "Beverages", "Cafe", "Desserts"],
      avgRating: 4.3,
     }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code and description you provided,The approach looks mostly correct, but there's a small issue in the way you are handling the filter data function and the restaurant data.

The main problem lies in how you are handling the filtering and updating the state. Since React's state updates are asynchronous, directly using the `searchText` value to filter the `restaurants` may not give the desired result. The state update may not have happened immediately after setting the `searchText`, so you might get an inconsistent or outdated filter result.

To fix this, you can utilize the `useEffect` hook to update the filtered data whenever the `searchText` changes. This way, the filter function will always operate on the latest state. Here's the updated code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { restruntList } from '../constants';

function filterData(searchText, restaurants) {
  const filteredData = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
    restaurant.info.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );
  return filteredData;
}

const Body = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [filteredRestaurants, setFilteredRestaurants] = useState(restruntList);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = filterData(searchText, restruntList);
    setFilteredRestaurants(data);
  }, [searchText]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchText}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="restaurant-list">
        {filteredRestaurants.map((restaurant) => (
          <RestruntCard {...restaurant.info} key={restaurant.info.id} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Changes made in the code:

1. We changed the state variable name from `restaurants` to `filteredRestaurants` to avoid confusion between the original data and the filtered data.
2. We added a `useEffect` hook to handle the filtering whenever the `searchText` changes. This ensures that the filtered data is updated correctly.

Now, when you type in the search input, the filtering should take place immediately, and the restaurant list should be updated accordingly.